How do I use the `@argfile` argument with the groovyc compiler?
EDIT: I am looking for a workaround for Windows where I cannot put my entire Classpath on the command line with the -cp option due to limitations on command lengths. With Java I can place all of my arguments and very long Classpath into an @argfile, and I'm trying to do the same with Groovy.
I'm trying to use the @argfile option for the Groovy compiler as shown in the documentation. This command works to compile my application:
groovyc -cp config-1.4.2.jar HelloWorld.groovy

However, if I take everything after groovyc and put it in a file called "args", I get an error:
groovyc @args
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
-cp config-1.4.2.jar HelloWorld.groovy: -cp config-1.4.2.jar HelloWorld.groovy (
The system cannot find the file specified)

To simplify, I even tried just putting -v in the args file and again, it tells me that it couldn't find -v.
What am I doing wrong?

TL;DR:
You can not use @file for any arguments other than source files
So how can you achieve your goal: generate a shell-script, that calls
groovyc with all your generated arguments.
Why:
The online-docs are misleading or do not/no longer match the behaviour
of the actual feature.  If you check the summary from the actual
groovyc, this hints, that only source files are picked up that way:
% groovyc --help | grep -A1 '@'
      [<source-files>...]    The groovy source files to compile, or @-files
                               containing a list of source files to compile

And "list" again here is somewhat ambiguous, but what the code does is
basically this:

if the argument starts with @
then treat the rest as a file name

read the file line by line
add each line to the list of files to compile


else add the argument to the list of files to compile


Thank you for that explanation. Any idea how to work around the limitations for command line argument length on Windows? With Java I'm able to put my very lengthy classpath and JVM props in an @arg file and that solves it.

I suggest, you are asking this question too then. Your original question is
a X-Y-problem and your real problem should not be hidden in the comments of
an answer.

I'll make an edit to the original question, but do you have any suggestions about the Windows path length issue?
